# How I can use the Javascript variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I have that code:

```
function saveData(position, map) {
var latlng = marker.getPosition();
var late =  latlng.lat();
var longe = latlng.lng();
    <?php
    require("sql.php");
    session_start();
    $name = 'prova';
    $address = 'temare';    
    $type = 'bar';
    $late = "<script>document.getElementByID('late').value</script>";
    $longe ="<script>document.getElementByID('longe').value</script>";
```

I need to get late and longe variables in PHP but this doesn't work, anyone knows how I can do it?

Comment: where's the html for this and did you wrap the js in script tags? the question is unclear and how you're using this? on a server? as `file:///`?

Comment: A request must be sent (including the variables) as GET or POST so the PHP can process their values.

Comment: You can't use javascript variable in php. Because js is client side and php is server side. if you want to do any logic with the js variable, you should use ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access javascript variables using PHP as JavaScript is executed on **client side** ( browser ) and PHP on **server side**.

The best what you can do is send data from those variables as request to server and read them, for example using jQuery ajax request:

Good example you can find here:
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Or you can use this:

**javascript**

```
function sendData(variable1, variable2) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'myphpscript.php'
        data: 'var1='+variable1+'&var2='+variable2
    });
```

**myphpscript.php**

```
<?php
$variable1 = $_POST['var1'];
$variable2 = $_POST['var2'];
```

Comment: This seems the most resonable answer but in the function sendData how I call the myphpscript.php?

Comment: I tried what you post but it seems it go to myphpscript

Comment: You must have included jQuery framework in your HTML, URL is the path where your php script is located from root eg.:
index.html
app/myphpscript.php will be url: 'app/myphpscript.php' as index html is in the root.

Comment: Yes, I have included jQuery framework but now my index.php doesn't load anything.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for everything I keep trying

Comment: Now loads the page but it still doesnt get the good value, here's the code:

Comment: function placeMarker(position, map) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: position,
       map: map
     });  
  
     var latlng = marker.getPosition();
  var late =  latlng.lat();
  var longe = latlng.lng();
   $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'myphpscript.php',
   data: 'var1='+late+'&var2='+longe
      });
   }

Comment: I don't see where you calling placeMarker, you must call function place marker before you sending request. Also keep in mind that request might be async, so first you have to check if placeMarker ( google maps ) recieved data before you sending them.

Comment: I have that call:

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
      placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
    });

Comment: How you would check if placeMarker recived the data? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(late)</script>"?> 
<?php $def = "<script>document.write(longe)</script>"?> 

</script>
```